# List<T> OrderBy Alphabetical Order

Tags: c#, generics, list, lambda, sorting

I'm using C# on Framework 3.5.  I'm looking to quickly sort a Generic `List<T>`.  For the sake of this example, let's say I have a List of a `Person` type with a property of lastname.  How would I sort this List using a lambda expression?

```
List<Person> people = PopulateList();
people.OrderBy(???? => ?????)
```

Answer (score 745, accepted):

If you mean an in-place sort (i.e. the list is updated):

```
people.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.LastName, y.LastName));
```

If you mean a new list:

```
var newList = people.OrderBy(x=>x.LastName).ToList(); // ToList optional
```

Comment: I believe that first one wants to be 
people.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.LastName, y.LastName) < 0);

Comment: @James: I wouldn't think so. Comparison<T> returns int, not bool.

Comment: I wonder if you want to OrderBy Firstname and Lastname... what should you write?

Comment: var newList = people.OrderBy(x=>x.FirstName).ThenBy(x=>x.LastName).ToList();

Comment: How to sort if the data type in int. int.Compare?

Comment: @Faraz just use x.CompareTo(y). That is trickier for strings because a: nulls, and b: different ways if sorting strings (case sensitivity, culture, etc)

Comment: people.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.LastName, y.LastName));
If here datatype is int instead of string... Then how do I sort?
people.Sort((x, y) => int.Compare(x.price, y.price));?

Comment: @Faraz (x,y)=>x.price.CompareTo(y.price)

Comment: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Generic.Collections.IComparer<MySolution.ViewModels.Person>' because it is not a delegate type` is the error I get on the first one.

Answer (score 107):

Do you need the list to be sorted in place, or just an ordered sequence of the contents of the list? The latter is easier:

```
var peopleInOrder = people.OrderBy(person => person.LastName);
```

To sort in place, you'd need an `IComparer<Person>` or a `Comparison<Person>`. For that, you may wish to consider `ProjectionComparer` in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil).

(I know I keep bringing MiscUtil up - it just keeps being relevant...)

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I appended ".ToList()":
contemporariesOrderedByBirthYear = contemporaries.OrderBy(contemp => contemp.BirthYear).ToList();

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: Well you need that if you want a `List<T>`, but you don't need it if you just want to iterate.

Answer (score 28):

```
people.OrderBy(person => person.lastname).ToList();
```

Comment: Well, that still doesn't capture the result - you'd need a "List<Person> people = " on the left hand side...

Comment: This answer demonstates most common error when using LINQ - methods like `OrderBy` *do not* modify list, but rather return new "collection" (usually lazy `IEnumerable<T>`) that need to be assigned to something.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov how do you know this is the most common error when using LINQ?

Answer (score 25):

you can use linq :) using :

```
System.linq;
var newList = people.OrderBy(x=>x.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 15):

```
private void SortGridGenerico< T >(
          ref List< T > lista       
    , SortDirection sort
    , string propriedadeAOrdenar)
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propriedadeAOrdenar)
    && lista != null
    && lista.Count > 0)
    {

        Type t = lista[0].GetType();

        if (sort == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {

            lista = lista.OrderBy(
                a => t.InvokeMember(
                    propriedadeAOrdenar
                    , System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty
                    , null
                    , a
                    , null
                )
            ).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            lista = lista.OrderByDescending(
                a => t.InvokeMember(
                    propriedadeAOrdenar
                    , System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty
                    , null
                    , a
                    , null
                )
            ).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

for me [this useful dummy guide - Sorting in Generic List -](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/CSHARP/84_Sorting_in_Generic_List.aspx)   worked.
it helps you to understand 4 ways(overloads) to do this job with very complete and clear explanations and simple examples

- List.Sort ()
- List.Sort (Generic Comparison)
- List.Sort (Generic IComparer)
- List.Sort (Int32, Int32, Generic IComparer)

Comment: Sort() is very useful especially when it's a List<string>()

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code snippet:

```
var New1 = EmpList.OrderBy(z => z.Age).ToList();
```

where `New1` is a `List<Employee>`.

`EmpList` is variable of a `List<Employee>`.

`z` is a variable of `Employee` type.

Comment: AnshuMan, there is nothing like a `var` type. `New1` is `List<Employee>` and `z` is `Employee`.

Comment: @nawfal There is a var type in C#. Or you can also use dynamic instead of var.

Comment: @lightlessdays var is a keyword, there is no var type in C#. And don't use dynamic for cases like this.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use

```
model.People = model.People.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: While this code sample may answer the question, it lacks explanation. As it stands now, it adds no value, and stands the change of being downvoted / deleted. Please add some explanation what is does and why it is a solution for the problem of the OP.

Answer (score 2):

This is a generic sorter. Called with the switch below.

dvm.PagePermissions is a property on my ViewModel of type 
    List T in this case T is a EF6 model class called page_permission.

dvm.UserNameSortDir is a string property on the viewmodel that holds the next sort direction.  The one that is actaully used in the view.

```
switch (sortColumn)
{
    case "user_name":
        dvm.PagePermissions = Sort(dvm.PagePermissions, p => p.user_name, ref sortDir);
        dvm.UserNameSortDir = sortDir;
        break;
    case "role_name":
        dvm.PagePermissions = Sort(dvm.PagePermissions, p => p.role_name, ref sortDir);
        dvm.RoleNameSortDir = sortDir;
        break;
    case "page_name":
        dvm.PagePermissions = Sort(dvm.PagePermissions, p => p.page_name, ref sortDir);
        dvm.PageNameSortDir = sortDir;
        break;
}                 


public List<T> Sort<T,TKey>(List<T> list, Func<T, TKey> sorter, ref string direction)
    {
        if (direction == "asc")
        {
            list = list.OrderBy(sorter).ToList();
            direction = "desc";
        }
        else
        {
            list = list.OrderByDescending(sorter).ToList();
            direction = "asc";
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: I think that this is way too complicated. As you can see in the other answers, it can all be done in one single line (it doesn't necessarily mean that doing it in a single line is good, but I don't get the advantage of doing it like this)

Comment: This is for multi column sorting using AngularJS.  It is essentially the single line sorting but it also sets the sort diretion variable.  Its really not that complex if you look at it closely. I guess the Sort function is a little intimidating with all the generic stuff but if I took that definition out it is a 1 line Sort call.

Comment: Too complicated for what the Op requested. It is a good solution for a different problem though.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 7 preview you can use the [simplified ordering](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-7-preview-7/#usage) of `System.Linq`. It also has some performance improvements.

```
var sorted = people.Order();
```

Also, be aware that the `Sort` method has a better performance in most cases because you don't allocate a new list.