# C# List<> Sort by x then y

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

Similar to [List<> OrderBy Alphabetical Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188141/c-list-orderby-alphabetical-order), we want to sort by one element, then another.  we want to achieve the functional equivalent of

```
SELECT * from Table ORDER BY x, y
```

We have a class that contains a number of sorting functions, and we have no issues sorting by one element.
For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int x;
    public int y;
}  

List<MyClass> MyList;

public void SortList() {
    MyList.Sort( MySortingFunction );
}
```

And we have the following in the list:

```
Unsorted     Sorted(x)     Desired
---------    ---------    ---------
ID   x  y    ID   x  y    ID   x  y
[0]  0  1    [2]  0  2    [0]  0  1
[1]  1  1    [0]  0  1    [2]  0  2
[2]  0  2    [1]  1  1    [1]  1  1
[3]  1  2    [3]  1  2    [3]  1  2
```

Stable sort would be preferable, but not required. Solution that works for .Net 2.0 is welcome.

Comment: @Bolu I've explicitly removed the tag to make post version agnostic and updated answers to match that. Consider making a clarifying edit in the question instead of restoring the tag if you think 4.0/2.0 was not prominent enough.

Comment: Sorry @AlexeiLevenkov, didn't pay much attention, please feel free to roll-back.

Comment: OK. Reverted the change.

Comment: This question was updated to cover all versions of .Net from original just 2.0 - contains several alternative answers for different frameworks and requirements - check out all to see which one fits your requirements better.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Do keep in mind that you don't need a stable sort if you compare all members.  The 2.0 solution, as requested, can look like this:

```
 public void SortList() {
     MyList.Sort(delegate(MyClass a, MyClass b)
     {
         int xdiff = a.x.CompareTo(b.x);
         if (xdiff != 0) return xdiff;
         else return a.y.CompareTo(b.y);
     });
 }
```

Do note that this 2.0 solution is still preferable over the popular 3.5 Linq solution, it performs an in-place sort and does not have the O(n) storage requirement of the Linq approach.  Unless you prefer the original List object to be untouched of course.

Answer (score 158):

For versions of .Net where you can use LINQ `OrderBy` and [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534743(v=vs.100).aspx) (or `ThenByDescending` if needed):

```
using System.Linq;
....
List<SomeClass>() a;
List<SomeClass> b = a.OrderBy(x => x.x).ThenBy(x => x.y).ToList();
```

---

Note: for .Net 2.0 (or if you can't use LINQ) see [Hans Passant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/289040/477420) to this question.

Comment: From another answer post by phoog here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285426/orderby-and-list-vs-iorderedenumerable  It creates another list with the original items in a new order. This is only useful if you need to preserve the original ordering for some other purpose; it's rather more wasteful of memory than sorting the list in place

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to implement a stable sort. I've created a Widget class that can contain your test data:

```
public class Widget : IComparable
{
    int x;
    int y;
    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set { y = value; }
    }

    public Widget(int argx, int argy)
    {
        x = argx;
        y = argy;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        int result = 1;
        if (obj != null && obj is Widget)
        {
            Widget w = obj as Widget;
            result = this.X.CompareTo(w.X);
        }
        return result;
    }

    static public int Compare(Widget x, Widget y)
    {
        int result = 1;
        if (x != null && y != null)                
        {                
            result = x.CompareTo(y);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I implemented IComparable, so it can be unstably sorted by List.Sort().

However, I also implemented the static method Compare, which can be passed as a delegate to a search method.

I borrowed this insertion sort method from [C# 411](http://www.csharp411.com/c-stable-sort/):

```
 public static void InsertionSort<T>(IList<T> list, Comparison<T> comparison)
        {           
            int count = list.Count;
            for (int j = 1; j < count; j++)
            {
                T key = list[j];

                int i = j - 1;
                for (; i >= 0 && comparison(list[i], key) > 0; i--)
                {
                    list[i + 1] = list[i];
                }
                list[i + 1] = key;
            }
    }
```

You would put this in the sort helpers class that you mentioned in your question.

Now, to use it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Widget> widgets = new List<Widget>();

        widgets.Add(new Widget(0, 1));
        widgets.Add(new Widget(1, 1));
        widgets.Add(new Widget(0, 2));
        widgets.Add(new Widget(1, 2));

        InsertionSort<Widget>(widgets, Widget.Compare);

        foreach (Widget w in widgets)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(w.X + ":" + w.Y);
        }
    }
```

And it outputs:

```
0:1
0:2
1:1
1:2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This could probably be cleaned up with some anonymous delegates, but I'll leave that up to you.

**EDIT**: And NoBugz demonstrates the power of anonymous methods...so, consider mine more oldschool :P

Answer (score 3):

This may help you,
[How to Sort C# Generic List](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/CSHARP/84_Sorting_in_Generic_List.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue where OrderBy and ThenBy did not give me the desired result (or I just didn't know how to use them correctly).

I went with a list.Sort solution something like this.

```
    var data = (from o in database.Orders Where o.ClientId.Equals(clientId) select new {
    OrderId = o.id,
    OrderDate = o.orderDate,
    OrderBoolean = (SomeClass.SomeFunction(o.orderBoolean) ? 1 : 0)
    });

    data.Sort((o1, o2) => (o2.OrderBoolean.CompareTo(o1.OrderBoolean) != 0
    o2.OrderBoolean.CompareTo(o1.OrderBoolean) : o1.OrderDate.Value.CompareTo(o2.OrderDate.Value)));
```