# C# - Sorting using Extension Method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I want to sort a list of person say

```
List<Person> persons=new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person("Jon","Bernald",45000.89));
persons.Add(new Person("Mark","Drake",346.89)); 
persons.Add(new Person("Bill","Watts",456.899));
```

based on

```
public enum CompareOptions
 {
    ByFirstName,
    ByLastName,
    BySalary
 }

 public enum SortOrder
 {
   Ascending,
   Descending
 }
```

using lambda expression what is the way to go for sorting?

```
    public static List<Person> SortPeople(this List<Person> lst, 
   CompareOptions opt1,SortOrder ord)

        {
           lst.Sort((p,op1,op2)=>{ how to apply lambda expression here});
        }
```

Comment: Good question. You are making the experts produce compact & readable code. We all learn from this. Thanks!!

Comment: @Shahkalpesh ,You too helped me well for my old questions.I would like to take this opportunity to thank you once again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to call the Sort method on `List<T>` which takes a `Comparison<T>` delegate.  This will require a bit of work because you first have to define a compatible comparison function.

First step is to write a comparison function based on the `CompareOptions` value

```
private static Comparison<Person> Create(CompareOptions opt) {
  switch (opt) {
    case CompareOptions.ByFirstName: (x,y) => x.FirstName.CompareTo(y.FirstName);
    case CompareOptions.ByLastName: (x,y) => x.LastName.CompareTo(y.LastName);
    case CompareOptions.BySalary: (x,y) => x.Salary - y.Salary;
    default: throw new Exception();
  }
}
```

By default this function will sort in ascending order.  If you want it to be descending simply negate the value.  So now writing SortPeople can be done by the following

```
public static List<Person> SortPeople(
   this List<Person> list, 
   CompareOptions opt1,
   SortOrder ord) )
   var original = Create(opt1);
   var comp = original;
   if( ord == SortOrder.Descending ) {
     comp = (x,y) => -(orig(x,y));
   }
   list.Sort(comp);
}
```

**EDIT**

Version which is done 100% in a lambda

```
public static List<Person> SortPeople(
   this List<Person> list, 
   CompareOptions opt1,
   SortOrder ord) )

   list.Sort( (x,y) => {
     int comp = 0;
     switch (opt) {
       case CompareOptions.ByFirstName: comp = x.FirstName.CompareTo(y.FirstName);
       case CompareOptions.ByLastName: comp = x.LastName.CompareTo(y.LastName);
       case CompareOptions.BySalary: comp = x.Salary.CompareTo(y.Salary);
       default: throw new Exception();
     }
     if ( ord == SortOrder.Descending ) {
       comp = -comp;
     }
     return comp;
   });
}
```

Comment: This is nice and clean, but it doesn't really show how to do it in a lambda, which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Reed Copsey I wouldn't recommend doing it in just one lamba, as every comparision will transverse all the ifs, not just one time to choose the correct lambda to use.

Comment: @Reed, true, I updated the answer to include a pure lambda version.

Comment: Oh, I agree - as I said, this is very clean (the first, unedited one), but the question was specifically how to do it there...

Comment: @Jared: I am naive to put this. But you could have comp initialized with int comp = (ord == SortOrder.Descending ? -1 : 1); and inside the switch block, you could write return comp * x.FirstName.CompareTo(y.FirstName); Let me know, if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Jared: Doesn't this require break; inside the switch? I haven't tried that piece of code.

Comment: @Jared :Error at comp => x.Salary - y.Salary; instead can we use x.Salary.CompareTo(Y.Salary) ?

Answer (score 6):

Do you really need the enums? I don't think that encapsulating your search logic in a method is much clearer or more DRY than just using linq methods:

```
persons.OrderBy( p => p.FirstName );
persons.OrderByDescending( p => p.Salary);
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

To get this to work in a lambda, the expression needs to form a [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) signature.  This would take 2 "Person" instances.  You could do this like:

```
public static void SortPeople(
    this List<Person> lst, CompareOptions opt1,SortOrder ord)
{
    lst.Sort((left, right) => 
             {
                 int result;
                 // left and right are the two Person instances
                 if (opt1 == CompareOptions.Salary)
                 {
                     result = left.Salary.CompareTo(right.Salary);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     string compStr1, compStr2;
                     if (opt1 == CompareOptions.FirstName)
                     {
                          compStr1 = left.FirstName;
                          compStr2 = right.FirstName;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                          compStr1 = left.LastName;
                          compStr2 = right.LastName;
                     }
                     result = compStr1.CompareTo(compStr2);
                 }
                 if (ord == SortOrder.Descending)
                     result *= -1;
                 return result;
             });
}
```

Comment: The extension method needs to have return type void.

Comment: It does.  The "return result" is the Comparsion<T> returning the sorting order.  The extension method is just { lst.Sort(...); }

Comment: No, I'm just saying that the SortPeople method has a return type of List<Person> which it does not return, but I guess you just copied it from his example...

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry - good catch, fixed.  I just copied it from the OP, which had this setup that way, too...

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
     class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>(); 
        persons.Add(new Person("Jon", "Bernald", 45000.89)); 
        persons.Add(new Person("Mark", "Drake", 346.89)); 
        persons.Add(new Person("Bill", "Watts", 456.899));

        persons.SortPeople(CompareOptions.ByFirstName, SortOrder.Ascending);

        persons.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.ToString()));

        persons.SortPeople(CompareOptions.ByFirstName, SortOrder.Descending);

        persons.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.ToString()));

        persons.SortPeople(CompareOptions.ByLastName, SortOrder.Ascending);

        persons.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.ToString()));

        persons.SortPeople(CompareOptions.ByLastName, SortOrder.Descending);

        persons.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.ToString()));

        persons.SortPeople(CompareOptions.BySalary, SortOrder.Ascending);

        persons.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.ToString()));

        persons.SortPeople(CompareOptions.BySalary, SortOrder.Descending);

        persons.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.ToString()));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void SortPeople(this List<Person> lst, CompareOptions opt1,SortOrder ord){
        lst.Sort((Person p1, Person p2) => 
            {
                switch (opt1)
                {
                    case CompareOptions.ByFirstName:
                        return ord == SortOrder.Ascending ? p1.FirstName.CompareTo(p2.FirstName) : p2.FirstName.CompareTo(p1.FirstName);
                    case CompareOptions.ByLastName:
                        return ord == SortOrder.Ascending ? p1.LastName.CompareTo(p2.LastName) : p2.LastName.CompareTo(p1.LastName);
                    case CompareOptions.BySalary:
                        return ord == SortOrder.Ascending ? p1.Salary.CompareTo(p2.Salary) : p2.Salary.CompareTo(p1.Salary);
                    default:
                        return 0;
                }
            });
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public double Salary { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person(string first, string last, double salary)
    {
        this.Salary = salary;
        this.FirstName = first;
        this.LastName = last;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1} has a salary of {2}", this.FirstName, this.LastName, this.Salary);
    }
}

public enum CompareOptions { ByFirstName, ByLastName, BySalary }
public enum SortOrder { Ascending, Descending }
```

}