# Looking for an inbuilt ordered list in C#

Tags: c#, list

I'm having a problem ordering the lists in C#. The solutions I come up with are unwieldy and seem a bit of a hack to me. I am looking for an elegant solution to the problem described below.
I want to make the ordering remain in the class to avoid using .Sort() or .OrderBy() in other parts of the code.
A 9 year old posting suggests that no such class/solution exists. But, I cannot help feeling there is something similar to an OrderedList somewhere which is not an IDictionary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                var obj = new Class1();
                obj.Test();
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            var myList = new List<MyObject>();

            myList.Add(new MyObject { Id = 1, Name = "ZZZ" });
            myList.Add(new MyObject { Id = 2, Name = "NNN" });
            myList.Add(new MyObject { Id = 3, Name = "PPP" });
            myList.Add(new MyObject { Id = 4, Name = "AAA" });

            foreach (var obj in myList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{obj.Name} -> {obj.Id}");
            }

        }

        public class MyObject
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

        }
    }
}
```

And the list is printed out in the order:

```
ZZZ -> 1
NNN -> 2
PPP -> 3
AAA -> 4
```

Could anyone suggest an appropriate class for an ordered list which would deliver:

```
AAA -> 4
NNN -> 2
PPP -> 3
ZZZ -> 1
```

Comment: Do they need to be **stored** in order? Can you `OrderBy` them with LINQ as needed instead? `foreach (var obj in myList.OrderBy(z => z.Name)`

Comment: Suggest an appropriate class?  Why don't you just sort them by name?

Comment: [Is this what you were describing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925471/sorting-a-list-of-objects-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I want them stored in order. I'll tweak the question to make that clear.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netframework-4.8 may be worth a read, if the names are unique.

Comment: Sorting by  name means it needs to be done throughout. This is an existing class, so I want the ordering to take place without propagating the change throughout (hopefully that makes sense)

Comment: To be clear, sorting a list is fairly easy. But making a list so that it is sorted internally irrespective of the order of added objects is harder. I could write one, but I feel there must already exist some sort of ordered list with an IComparer. However, it eludes me :)

Comment: When you say " I want the ordering to take place without propagating the change throughout", I'm not sure I follow.  Do you want to display the re-ordered list without actually changing the list order?

Comment: @Regianni Why do you want to write one? Did you read the docs for `SortedList` / `SortedDictionary`? Could you use either of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there no SortedList<T> in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663613/why-is-there-no-sortedlistt-in-net)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Multiple options here:

Sort the list in place:

```
myList.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name));
```

Sort the list in place with a comparer:

```
class MyObjectNameComparer : IComparer<MyObject>
{
    public int Compare(MyObject x, MyObject y)
    {
        return string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
    }
}

myList.Sort(new MyObjectNameComparer());
```

Mark your class as `IComparable<MyObject>` and then sort in place. This will affect the behavior of `Comparer<MyObject>.Default`:

```
class MyObject : IComparable<MyObject>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(MyObject other)
    {
        return string.Compare(this.Name, other.Name);
    }
}

// then
myList.Sort();
```

Use linq to iterate in a sorted manner, but keep the list as-is:

```
foreach (var myObject in myList.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
{
    // ordered results
}
```

Use a `SortedList`, which is somewhat like a dictionary, but then sorted on a key instead of a hashcode. That means you need unique 'names' (keys) for each object:

```
var sortedList = new SortedList<string, MyObject>();
sortedList.Add("ZZZ", new MyObject { Id = 1, Name = "ZZZ" });
sortedList.Add("NNN", new MyObject { Id = 2, Name = "NNN" });
sortedList.Add("PPP", new MyObject { Id = 3, Name = "PPP" });
sortedList.Add("AAA", new MyObject { Id = 4, Name = "AAA" });
// Below would fail, because the key needs to be unique...
// sortedList.Add("AAA", new MyObject { Id = 5, Name = "AAA" });

foreach (var entry in sortedList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Value.Name} -> {entry.Value.Id}");
}
```

Or use a `SortedSet<T>`, which maintains ordered, unique items (i.e. you cannot add doubles).

```
var set = new SortedSet<MyObject>(new MyObjectNameComparer());
set.Add(new MyObject { Id = 1, Name = "ZZZ" });
// etc.
```

Create a custom collection, with an ordered enumerator. That would let clients iterate over the items in a sorted manner. This version is 'optimized' on inserts:

```
class OrderedMyObjectCollection : ICollection<MyObject>
{
    private List<MyObject> innerList = new List<MyObject>();
    public int Count => this.innerList.Count;
    public bool IsReadOnly => false;
    public void Add(MyObject item) => this.innerList.Add(item);
    public void Clear() => this.innerList.Clear();
    public bool Contains(MyObject item) => this.innerList.Contains(item);

    public void CopyTo(MyObject[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        // Could be more efficient...
        this.ToList().CopyTo(array);
    }

    // Magic in the ordered enumerator.
    public IEnumerator<MyObject> GetEnumerator() => this.innerList.OrderBy(x => x.Name).GetEnumerator();
    public bool Remove(MyObject item) => this.innerList.Remove(item);
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => this.GetEnumerator();
}
```

If you need to optimize on iteration, you could actually store the items at the right index on add:

```
class OrderedList<T> : IList<T>
{
    // see above for the comparer implementation 
    private readonly IComparer<T> comparer;
    private readonly IList<T> innerList = new List<T>();

    public OrderedList()
        : this(Comparer<T>.Default)
    {
    }

    public OrderedList(IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(comparer));
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get => this.innerList[index];
        set => throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot set an indexed item in a sorted list.");
    }

    public int Count => this.innerList.Count;
    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    // Magic in the insert
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        int index = innerList.BinarySearch(item, comparer);
        index = (index >= 0) ? index : ~index;
        innerList.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void Clear() => this.innerList.Clear();
    public bool Contains(T item) => this.innerList.Contains(item);
    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex) => this.innerList.CopyTo(array);
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => this.innerList.GetEnumerator();
    public int IndexOf(T item) => this.innerList.IndexOf(item);
    public void Insert(int index, T item) => throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot insert an indexed item in a sorted list.");
    public bool Remove(T item) => this.innerList.Remove(item);
    public void RemoveAt(int index) => this.innerList.RemoveAt(index);
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => this.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: All but the last one the OP has said aren't acceptable. It may be worth highlighting that the last one relies on unique keys.

Comment: So close, but good answer Jesse. In the code I am updating, the Add() method is out of my control in that it is used throughout. I would have to change things around externally. Although the list has all it needs with the comparer now. This is the issue I am having. It needs to list like a List<MyObject> externally.

Comment: @JessedeWit looks good, I'll let you know once I've finished spinning other plates.

Comment: you're missing [SortedSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @johnny5 Great addition. Added it in the answer.

Comment: The title is asking for a built in ordered list, not how to sort an unordered list, despite what the OP's body text says.

Answer (score 2):

Think I finally came across this, which is as simple as I can find. Never heard of SortedSet before.

```
    public void Test()
    {
        var myList = new SortedSet<MyObject>(new MyComparer());

        myList.Add(new MyObject { Id = 1, Name = "ZZZ" });
        myList.Add(new MyObject { Id = 2, Name = "NNN" });
        myList.Add(new MyObject { Id = 3, Name = "PPP" });
        myList.Add(new MyObject { Id = 4, Name = "AAA" });

        foreach (var obj in myList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{obj.Name} -> {obj.Id}");
        }
    }

    public class MyComparer : IComparer<MyObject>
    {
        public int Compare(MyObject x, MyObject y) => String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```