# sorting list of structures by values of the struct #

Tags: c#, list, sorting, struct

I have a list of structures, where my struct looks like this:

```
struct coordinate
{
  int x;
  int y;
}
```

I want the list sorted initialy by the x value of the struct, and if there are(from the sorted structs) structs with the same x (like coordinate[1].x = coordinate[2].x), sort it then by y. It's possible in C#?
I've already sorted them by x

```
List.Sort((s1, s2) => s1.x.CompareTo(s2.x));
```

but I dont know how to make the second step.
please help :)

Comment: `var sortedList = list.OrderBy(r=> r.x).ThenBy(r=> r.y).ToList();`

Comment: In the marked duplicate, the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2779462/414076) (based on current votes) gives you the inline sort that matches your question. If you prefer producing a *new* ordered list, then the first answer is applicable.