# List<data class>.sort on multiple criteria

Tags: c#

I have a list populated with a custom data class, the list has column values `string` (Type) as well as `double` (Xo).  I can successfully sort the list using two lines of code, is it possible to do the `.Sort` in one line?

```
        List.Sort((x, y) => x.Xo.CompareTo(y.Xo));
        List.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(y.Type, x.Type));
```

Comment: Have you tried  `List.Sort((x, y) => x.Xo.CompareTo(y.Xo) && string.Compare(y.Type, x.Type))`

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779375/order-a-list-c-by-many-fields

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I specifically asked using the .Sort function, not using the order by and thenorderby..

Comment: Then have a look at the second-highest voted answer from tster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
var sorted = items.OrderBy(x => x.Xo).ThenBy(x => x.Type).ToList();
```

Comment: Seems like OP wants tom use `Sort`. not `OrderBy`.