# Linq Query OrderBy Multiple

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a `List<Employees>` collection that I am trying to select `Active` employees on.

I must be doing something wrong, because I see numerous examples on here showing that I can do this, yet Visual Studio is telling me I can not because:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What is wrong with this picture? `LastName` and `FirstName` (as you might suspect) are both String values, and `Active` is a Boolean.

[image: range variable]

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = null;
List<AcpEmployee> emps = from e in employeeInfo.Employees
                         where e.Active 
                         orderby e.LastName, e.FirstName descending
                         select e;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [OrderBy and List vs. IOrderedEnumerable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285426/orderby-and-list-vs-iorderedenumerable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just append a ToList() to your query if you want the result as a list. or simply declare emps as `var emps` which will have a type `IOrderedEnumerable`

Answer (score 9):

You should use `ToList` at the end of your query:

```
List<AcpEmployee> emps = (  from e in employeeInfo.Employees
                            where e.Active
                            orderby e.Active orderby e.LastName, e.FirstName descending
                            select e).ToList();
```

or using the methods directly:

```
List<AcpEmployee> emps = employeeInfo.Employees
    .Where(e => e.Active)
    .OrderBy(e => e.LastName)
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.FirstName)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been [answered here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq), just use the orderby keyword in linq

```
var emps = from e in employeeInfo.Employees 
            where e.Active orderby e.LastName thenby e.FirstName select e;
```

Comment: `orderby` or `thenby`? It still gives the error because my code is specifically trying to assign it to a `List<T>`.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that assignment, L.B is right then just add the .ToList()