# OrderBy clause breaks my controller in Entity Framework Core 3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

So I had this little controller that is working great.  The only issue, is that the `StateLocation` OrderId was out of order in the returned string.

```
[HttpGet("GetLocationsByLanguageId/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<LanguageList>>> GetLocationsByLanguageId(Guid id)
{
    var choicesByLanguage = await _context.LanguageList.Where(q => q.LanguageId == id)
                    .Include(p => p.StateLocation)
                    .ToListAsync();
    return choicesByLanguage;
}
```

So I went to the Microsoft Entity Framework site to read about ordering and found this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

So I added an `OrderBy` clause like you see below:

```
[HttpGet("GetLocationsByLanguageId/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<LanguageList>>> GetLocationsByLanguageId(Guid id)
{
    var choicesByLanguage = await _context.LanguageList.Where(q => q.LanguageId == id)
                    .Include(p => p.StateLocation
                            .OrderBy(p => p.OrderId))
                            .ToListAsync();
    return choicesByLanguage;
}
```

I don't get any errors on build, but when I try to hit the site, I get this:

> Expression of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable' cannot be used for
> return type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable

So I searched around for that found a few possible solutions here:

[OrderBy and List vs. IOrderedEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285426/orderby-and-list-vs-iorderedenumerable/9285461)

But none of those worked, they just generated new errors or variations on of the original error.

I've had trouble finding any answers that help with this issue when using .Net Core 3.  Most of the answers are for older versions.

Has anyone been able to solve this .Net Core Entity Framework 3.0?

Thanks!

Models:

```
public partial class LanguageList
{
    public LanguageList()
    {
        StateLocation = new HashSet<StateLocation>();
    }
    
    public Guid LanguageId{ get; set; }
    public string LanguageName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StateLocation> StateLocation { get; set; }
}

public partial class StateLocation
{
    public Guid StateId { get; set; }
    public Guid LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public string StateCapital { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual LanguageList Language { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show StateLocation and  LanguageList classes pls?

Comment: Could you check your syntax again? You have a `)` too many in the last code block

Comment: @Xerillio oops thanks, just a typo when I was typing it out here on SO. :)

Comment: @Sergey yep, just added! Thanks!

Comment: Not sure it makes sense to order an include...

Comment: @MarcGravell why?  The StateLocations are children of the LanguageList and they need to be ordered by their orderId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
return  await _context.LanguageList
                    .Where(q => q.LanguageId == id)
                    .Include(p => p.StateLocation.OrderBy(p => p.OrderId))
                     .ToListAsync();
```

You almost made this query, but since you put the extra ")" in a wrong place it gave the error.

but if you still use EF Core 3 you can try this:

```
var query=  await _context.LanguageList
              .Where(q => q.LanguageId == id)
        .Select(p => new
        {
            P = p,
            C = p.StateLocation.OrderBy(p => p.OrderId))
        })
    .ToListAsync();

return  query
            .Select(g => g.P)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Is this actually supported? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378136/entity-framework-ordering-includes) indicates otherwise - it's an old post though

Comment: I think that's what I am using?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell AFAIK, `.OrderBy()` inside `.Include()` is a feature introduced in EF Core 5.0.

Comment: @atiyar Oh I see, I am using 3.1.  Is there no way to do this in 3.1?  Thanks :(

Answer (score 1):

You mention you're using EF Core 3, however, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) states that this functionality was first introduced in EF Core 5.0. That is, you cannot perform LINQ operations on the related data in a single query. Instead you need to either upgrade to EF Core 5.0 or perform the ordering **after** your `ToListAsync` call.

Example in EF Core 3:

```
var choicesByLanguage = await _context.LanguageList.Where(q => q.LanguageId == id)
    .Include(p => p.StateLocation)
    .ToListAsync();

foreach (var lList in choicesByLanguage)
{
    lList.StateLocation = lList.StateLocation.OrderBy(p => p.OrderId).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I tried `.ToListAsync().OrderBy(p => p.OrderId) ` but it doesn't recognize it

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell I added an example. The problem with your example there is that `ToListAsync()` returns the list of `LanguageList` which doesn't have the `OrderId` property - it's in a child object.