# How to sort generic list?

Tags: c#, .net, list

I need to make ascending sort of generic List.
Here is my generic type:

```
public class ContainerData
{
   private Point pnt;
   private Size size;
   private Double Area;
   private Contour<Point> contour;

   public ContainerData()
   { }

   public ContainerData(ContainerData containerData)
   { 
     this.pnt=containerData.pnt;
     this.size=containerData.size;
     this.Area=containerData.Area;
     this.contour = containerData.contour;
   }

   public Point pointProperty
   {
       get
       {return pnt;}
       set
       {pnt = value;}
   }

   public Size sizeProperty
   {
       get
       {return size;}
       set
       {size = value;}
   }

   public Double AreaProperty
   {
       get
       {return Area;}
       set
       {Area = value;}
   }
   public Contour<Point> ContourProperty
   {
       get
       {return contour;}
       set
       { contour = value; }
   }
}
```

The ascending sorting have to be made under the value of X coordinate of th Point type.

Here is the  class member that sholud be sorted:

```
 private List<ContainerData> dataOfPreviusImage;
```

Any idea how can I implement it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Is [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx) that difficult to find?

Comment: If you dont want to use LINQ I suggest you to read this msdn page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx

Comment: You can also look into this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289010/c-sharp-list-sort-by-x-then-y/) also

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) :

```
List<ContainerData> dataOfPreviusImage = GetSomeData();
var sorted = dataOfPreviusImage.OrderBy(cd => cd.pointProperty.X);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a Compare Function :

```
private int SortFunction(ContainerData obj1, ContainerData obj2)
{
    return obj1.pointProperty.X.CompareTo(obj2.pointProperty.X);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
dataOfPreviusImage.Sort(new Comparison<ContainerData>(SortFunction));
```

Comment: inline version: `dataOfPreviusImage.Sort((obj1, obj2) => obj1.pointProperty.X.CompareTo(obj2.pointProperty.X));`

Answer (score 1):

To help you along your way, your ContainerData class should implement IComparable and ideally IEquateable as well.