# How can I sort the file txt line 5000000?

Tags: c#, sorting

i've got a disordered file with 500000 line which its information and date are like  the following :

```
for instance          desired Result
------------          ---------------      
 723,80                1,4   
 14,50                 1,5 
 723,2                 10,8
 1,5                   14,50 
 10,8                  723,2 
 1,4                   723,80
```

Now how can i implement such a thing ?

I've tried the sortedList and sorteddictionary methods but there is no way for implemeting a new value in the list because there are some repetative values in the list. 
I'd appreciate it if u suggest the best possible method .

One more thing , i've seen this question but this one uses the class while i go with File!

[C# List<> Sort by x then y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289010/c-sharp-list-sort-by-x-then-y)

Comment: What's wrong with using the link you posted?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you need to do. You obviously need to sort this list but what is the pattern..?

Comment: Yes, I want to sort the data inside the file, but there are duplicate values ​​that should
Be considered.

Comment: You can use what you linked. Feed your file into the class, and then write back out with them sorted. If that is your desired result.

Comment: Do you want to retain the duplicates or rationalise them to a single line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines("...filepath...")
                 .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                 .Select(parts => new
                 {
                     V1 = int.Parse(parts[0]),
                     V2 = int.Parse(parts[1])
                 })
                 .OrderBy(v => v.V1)
                 .ThenBy(v => v.V2)
                 .ToList();
```

Duplicates will be handled properly by default. If you want to remove them, add `.Distinct()` somewhere, for example after `ReadAllLines`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the file into an object defined by a class. Once it's in the object, you can start to sort it.

```
public class myObject
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
}
```

Now once you get the file parsed into a list of objects, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
var myList = new List<myObject>(); //obviously, you should have parsed the file into the list.
var sortedList = myList.OrderBy(l => l.x).ThenBy(l => l.y).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

First, sort each row so that they are in the correct order (e.g [723,80] - > [80,723]

Then sort all rows using a comparison something like this:

```
int Compare(Tuple<int,int> lhs, Tuple<int,int> rhs)
{
  int res = lhs.Item1.CompareTo(rhs.Item1)
  if(res == 0) res=lhs.Item2.CompareTo(rhs.Item2);

  return res;
}
```