# List<object> double sort

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting

I have a model like this.

```
 public class MenuItem
 {
      public string Description { get; set; }
      public string MenuTypeID { get; set; }
      public int DailyMax { get; set; }
 }
```

Then I have a method like this.

```
public List<MenuItem> GetMenuItem()
{
        List<MenuItem> menuItems = new List<MenuItem>();

        DataSet ds = null;
       .... left out ds populating code....

        try
        {
                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItemType();

                    menuItem.Description = dr["Description"].ToString();
                    menuItem.MenuTypeID = dr["MenuTypeID"].ToString();

                    menuItems.Add(menuItem);
                }

            List<MenuItemType> SortedList = menuItems.Sort((x, y) => x.MenuTypeID.CompareTo(y.MenuTypeID));
            // compile error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MenuItem>'
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {

        }

        return SortedList;
    }
```

My questions are,

1. How to sort without the compile error?
2. Is it possible to sort first by `menuTypeId`, then the `description`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object also here is another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289010/c-sharp-list-sort-by-x-then-y

Comment: `List<MenuItemType> SortedList = menuItems.Sort` `Sort` doesn't _return_ a list. It _sorts an existing one_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0) and [`ThenBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=net-5.0) methods:

```
var sortedList = menuItems.OrderBy(o => o.menuTypeId).ThenBy(c => c.Description).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how to fix the compile error?

Comment: @Prosper Just replace the `SortedList`'s line with the code cited above, you shouldn't see the error anymore.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<MenuItemType> SortedList = menuItems.Sort((x, y) => x.MenuTypeID.CompareTo(y.MenuTypeID));
// compile error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MenuItem>'
```

The `Sort` method sorts the current `List<>` instance in place, and its return type is `void`. So you should just use:

```
menuItems.Sort((x, y) => x.MenuTypeID.CompareTo(y.MenuTypeID));
```

and after that, the *same* list `menuItems` will be sorted in the desired way.

---

To address the part about sorting by two properties, the lambda becomes a bit uglier:

```
menuItems.Sort((x, y) =>
{
  var c = x.MenuTypeID.CompareTo(y.MenuTypeID);
  if (c != 0)
    return c;
  return x.Description.CompareTo(y.Description);
});
```

Another possibility is to let the underlying type (`class` or `struct`) `MenuItemType` implement the interface `IComparable<MenuItemType>`. The implementation will look like the portion between `{` and `}` above. Then you can simply do:

```
menuItems.Sort();
```

This possibility is best if the `MenuItemType` is "naturally" sortable in this way in all situations.

The last possibility, to use LINQ, can be seen in Salah Akbari's answer. Note that with that method, a new `List<>` is created, and the original `List<>` remains unchanged. You do not care about this in your example because the original list is created as `new List<...>` in the same method, and is not kept (saved) or used later. But in other contexts, it may be an advantage (or a problem) that the original `List<>` (to which other variables or objects may hold references) is unchanged.

In extreme cases where the `List<>` is really long (not in your example, I am sure), note that `.Sort` will be faster than LINQ's `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`.