# Sort an unbound dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist which I have populated with the following code:

```
statusList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Inactive_AddUser, "0"));
statusList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(Select, Select));
if (activeUser < (Convert.ToInt32(Session["MaxActiveUsers"])))
 {
   statusList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Active_AddUser, "1"));
 }
```

Now I'm unable to sort the list. Any suggestions on how can I implement it?

Comment: You have a list that always have 2 items? You don't need to sort it, just create it in an ordered way.

Comment: Manually add the items in a different order?

Comment: [How to sort a dropdown list - SO Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698266/how-to-sort-an-asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a `List` of `ListItem`s then sort it and after all bind it to `DropDownList` some thing like this that I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/227944/2040375):

```
List<ListItem> items;//fill this with your own items
items.Sort((x, y) => x.Text.CompareTo(y.Text));
statusList.DataSource = items;
statusList.DataBind();
```