# Sorting a collection in alphabetical order

Tags: c#, sorting

Is there any way, out of the box, to sort a collection in alphabetical order (using C# 2.0 ?).

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188141/c-list-orderby-alphabetical-order

Comment: @Dominic that question is about 3.5, which means Linq.

Comment: @Dominic: I see Q and most A using C#3

Comment: @Will, @Henk - sorry, should probably stay out of topics I know nothing about!

Comment: @Dom considering the subject of .NET versioning is confusing enough to c# devs, probably so!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What sort of collections are we talking about? A `List<T>`? `ICollection<T>`? Array? What is the type stored in the collection?

Assuming a `List<string>`, you can do this:

```
 List<string> str = new List<string>();
 // add strings to str

 str.Sort(StringComparer.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: I don't like using `var` in general situations

Comment: @thecoop Unless the context isn't readily visible, var is awesome

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

How about [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc.aspx)? Even if you don't supply a custom comparer, by default it'll sort the array in alphabetical order:

```
var array = new string[] { "d", "b" };

Array.Sort(array); // b, d
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>(theCollection);
stringList.Sort();
```

`List<string>` implements `ICollection<string>`, so you will still have all of the collection-centric functionality even after you convert to a list.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be out of the box, but you can also use LinqBridge http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx to do LINQ queries in 2.0 (Visual Studio 2008 is recommended though).