# C# - Sorting listbox alphabetically

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox

I need helping sorting a textfile alphabetically which has been read into a listbox. Is there any way of possibly having the list box sort this set of data which is contain in a textfile:

```
pizza, margherita, regular, 4.40, dough, 1.00, sauce, 0.25, mozzarella, 0.75
pizza, margherita, large, 5.40, dough, 1.44, sauce, 0.36, mozzarella, 1.08
pizza, margherita, extra-large, 7.50, dough, 1.79, sauce, 0.45, mozzarella, 1.34
pizza, pepperoni, regular, 5.00, dough, 1.00, sauce, 0.25, mozzarella, 0.75, pepperoni, 2.0
pizza, pepperoni, large, 6.00, dough, 1.44, sauce, 0.36, mozzarella, 1.08, pepperoni, 2.88
pizza, pepperoni, extra-large, 10.00, dough, 1.79, sauce, 0.45, mozzarella, 1.342, pepperoni, 3.58
pizza, hawaiian, regular, 5.50, dough, 1.00, sauce, 0.25, mozzarella, 0.75, ham, 1.50, pineapple, 0.5
pizza, hawaiian, large, 6.50, dough, 1.44, sauce, 0.36, mozzarella, 1.08, ham, 2.16, pineapple, 0.72
pizza, hawaiian, extra-large, 11.00, dough, 1.79, sauce, 0.45, mozzarella, 1.34, ham, 2.69, pineapple, 0.90
pizza, vegetable, regular, 5.40, dough, 1.00, sauce, 0.25, mozzarella, 0.75, olives, 0.75, spinach, 0.25, mushrooms, 1.00
pizza, vegetable, large, 6.40, dough, 1.44, sauce, 0.36, mozzarella, 1.08, olives, 1.08, spinach, 0.36, mushrooms, 1.44
pizza, vegetable, extra-large, 10.00, dough, 1.79, sauce, 0.45, mozzarella, 1.342, olives, 1.34, spinach, 0.45, mushrooms, 1.79
pizza, meaty, regular, 5.50, dough, 1.00, sauce, 0.25, mozzarella, 0.75, chicken, 0.50, beef, 0.50, ham, 0.25, pepperoni, 0.25
pizza, meaty, large, 6.50, dough, 1.44, sauce, 0.36, mozzarella, 1.08, chicken, 0.72, beef, 0.72, ham, 0.36, pepperoni, 0.36
pizza, meaty, extra-large, 13.00, dough, 1.79, sauce, 0.45, mozzarella, 1.34, chicken, 1.08, beef, 1.08, ham, 0.45, pepperoni, 0.45
burger, beef, regular, 2.30, bun, 1, beef patty, 1
burger, beef, large, 3.40, bun, 1, beef patty, 2
burger, chicken, regular, 3.00, bun, 1, chicken fillet, 1
burger, chicken, large, 4.10, bun, 1, chicken fillet, 2
burger, vegetarian, regular, 2.50, bun, 1, falafel, 1
burger, vegetarian, large, 3.60, bun, 1, falafel, 2
sundry, chips, regular, 1.20, chips, 1
sundry, onion-rings, regular, 1.70, onion rings, 1
sundry, coleslaw, regular, 1.00, coleslaw,
```

Comment: what field to order by?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sort(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: your stack is overflowing with pizzas. :)

Comment: The first field "caterogy" so that would be burger first then pizza then sundrys.

Comment: Found another post with a super answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494941/sorting-a-collection-in-alphabetical-order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build on Rob's answer, you could also create a static method on the `FoodItem` class that knows how to create a `FoodItem` from a comma-separated string. You could call this method when reading the file, to simplify generating a list of food items.

Also, overriding the `ToString()` property on these classes makes displaying the items much easier too.

Here's the `FoodItem` class with a few additions:

```
public class FoodItem
{
    public string FoodCategory { get; set; }
    public string FoodType { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

    public FoodItem()
    {
        Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>();
    }

    public static FoodItem CreateFromCommaString(string commaSeparatedValues)
    {
        var foodItem = new FoodItem();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(commaSeparatedValues)) return foodItem;

        var values = commaSeparatedValues.Split(',')
            .Select(value => value.Trim()).ToList();

        double price;
        foodItem.FoodCategory = values[0];
        if (values.Count > 1) foodItem.FoodType = values[1];
        if (values.Count > 2) foodItem.Size = values[2];
        if (values.Count > 3 && double.TryParse(values[3], out price))
        {
            foodItem.Price = price;
        }

        if (values.Count > 4)
        {
            for (int i = 4; i < values.Count; i += 2)
            {
                var ingredient = new Ingredient {Name = values[i]};
                double qty;
                if (values.Count > i + 1 && double.TryParse(values[i + 1], out qty))
                {
                    ingredient.Quantity = qty;
                }
                foodItem.Ingredients.Add(ingredient);
            }
        }

        return foodItem;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}: {1} ({2}) = ${3:0.00}. Contains: {4}",
            FoodCategory, FoodType, Size, Price, string.Join(", ", Ingredients));
    }
}
```

And the `Ingredient` class with a `ToString` override:

```
public class Ingredient
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name}: {Quantity}";
    }
}
```

Then, populating a list of the classes is simple: just get all the file lines, and for each one generate a new `FoodItem` and add it to your list. And once that's done, you can order the list by multiple fields, using `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var filePath = @"f:\public\temp\temp.txt";

    var foodItems = new List<FoodItem>();

    foreach (var fileLine in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
    {
        foodItems.Add(FoodItem.CreateFromCommaString(fileLine));
    }

    var sortedItems = foodItems
        .OrderBy(item => item.FoodCategory)
        .ThenBy(item => item.FoodType)
        .ThenBy(item => item.Price)
        .ToList();

    sortedItems.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output (click to enlarge):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Enable Sorted Property to true

listBox1.Sorted = true;

Answer (score 1):

Is there anyway you can change the way your values are stored?

For example. You have

Burger, Vegetarian, Large, 3.60, bun,1, falafel,2 all in one comma separated line.

How about

Burger, Vegetarian, Large, 3.60, bun:1|falafel:2 then you would know that you have 
Product, Type, Size, Price, Ingredients
and Ingredients is '|' separated and also, ':' between name and qty.

Anyway, if it was set out like that you could read it into a List of objects or a dictionary, so each item in the listbox can have the Key as the value, then you can use the values else where in the code easily.

```
public class FoodItem
{
   public string FoodCategory {get;set;}
   public string FoodType {get;set;}
   public string Size {get;set;}
   public double Price {get;set;}
   public List<Ingredient> Ingredients {get;set;}
}

public class Ingredient
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Quantity {get;set;}
}
```

Then when you read your text field parse each line into an instance of food item.

Another questions answer reading text files line by line.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7980605/7683170