# array List Sorting according to the file extension

Tags: c#, arraylist

i am having some file names in array list Like, **"Form.frm,Form1.frm,Form2.frm,Module.bas,Module23.bas"**
in the array list i want to make the first item as **".bas"** files 
how can i make it using array list.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want the output to be? Also, is there any reason you're using an `ArrayList` instead of a `List<string>` -- `ArrayList` is obsolete.

Comment: Try having a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188141/c-sharp-list-orderby-alphabetical-order
Hope it helps.
Also try to use List<T> instead of Arrays, they are easier to handle

Comment: this is an existing code. already they are using arrylist only. if i change arraylist to List<string> means it will affect so many place.

Comment: i am working on migrating tool vb to C# ".bas" files are like class file in vb. so that i want read class file first to fetch all the variables and function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to order the items by the extension, this can be done in this way:

```
        List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
        fileNames.Add("Form.frm");
        fileNames.Add("Form1.frm");
        fileNames.Add("Form2.frm");
        fileNames.Add("Module.bas");
        fileNames.Add("Module23.bas");

        var ordered = fileNames.OrderBy(p => Path.GetExtension(p));
```

Comment: Damn 5 minutes of slow connection :(

Answer (score 5):

First i would suggest to use the strongly typed `List<T>` instead. You can use `Path.GetExtension` and Linq's `Enumerable.OrderBy`:

```
List<String> files = new List<String>(){ "Form2.frm","Module.bas","Module23.bas" };
var ordered = files.OrderBy(fn => Path.GetExtension(fn));
```