# null reference MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reference, null

I have the following code in my MVC3 homecontroller's Index method. What I am trying is, getting values from my Resource File (.resx) and show them in  a view.

```
private ResourceManager rm = null;
private ResourcesTexts text;

public ActionResult Index()
{
  text = new ResourcesTexts();
  rm = new ResourceManager("Credit.SiteResources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
  var res = rm.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);

foreach (DictionaryEntry resource in res)
{
  if (resource.Key.ToString().Count() == 14)
    {
     string x = resource.Value.ToString();
    text.myList.Add(x);
    }
}

return View(text);
}
```

i am getting null reference error while debugging.

Any Help?

In my view I am trying something like this.

```
@foreach(var x in Model.myList.Item)
{
    <p>@x</p>
}
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: Where is the NullReferenceException?

Comment: is text.myList well initialized?

Comment: i guess yes. text = new ResourcesTexts();

Comment: I think the person that has answered, points what I meant to say :)

Comment: Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: yes thanks. but the retrieved values are not in order. How can i order the items of the list using LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
text = new ResourcesTexts();
text.myList = new List<string>();
```

OR

Create list in `ResourcesTexts` constructor

Comment: yes thanks. but the retrieved values are not in order. How can i order the items of the list using LINQ.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188141/c-sharp-list-orderby-alphabetical-order) you have another answer that can help you solve this.