# insert into a List alphabetically C#

Tags: c#, .net

Could anyone please teach me how to insert item into list in alphabetical order in C#?

So every time I add to the list I want to add an item alpabetically, the list could become quite large in theory.

Sample Code:

```
Public Class Person
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Age { get; set; }
}

Public Class Storage
{
    private List<Person> people;

    public Storage
    {
        people = new List<Person>();
    }


    public void addToList(person Person)
    {
        int insertIndex = movies.findindex(
            delegate(Movie movie) 
            {
              return //Stuck here, or Completely off Track.

            }
        people.insert(insertIndex, newPerson);
    }

}
```

Comment: Here in this Stackoverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188141/c-sharp-list-orderby-alphabetical-order

Comment: @John3136 Inserting in the appropriate position is not the same as re-sorting the list after each insert.

Comment: Use a specialized collection - e.g. sortedlist.  List.Insert isn't an efficient solution in terms of LOC, bugs, cpu, memory, programmer time etc.

Comment: Kirk - I don't see where I suggested that it was. My intent was to find one of the existing sorted collection classes rather than finding out how to sort a collection.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Old thread, but the answers in this thread IMO are ignoring OP's actual question.  The question is straightforward - how do you insert into a list in sorted order.  That's not the same as "just use a SortedSet / SortedList".  There will be different characteristics and implications based on using the below vs. using a SortedList.

SortedSet and SortedList are both based off of Dictionary, and won't allow you to add two items with the same key AFAIK.

So how do you account for a list such as, { a, b, c, c, d }?

Here is the correct way to insert into an ordered list so that the items remain ordered:

```
var binarySearchIndex = list.BinarySearch(item, itemComparer);
//The value will be a negative integer if the list already 
//contains an item equal to the one searched for above
if (binarySearchIndex < 0)
{
    list.Insert(~binarySearchIndex, item);
}
else
{
    list.Insert(binarySearchIndex, item);
}
```

Answer via this great article from 2010: https://debugmode.net/2010/09/18/inserting-element-in-sorted-generic-list-list-using-binary-search/

Comment: Great answer, thank you - actually answers the question!  I was a little stumped on `itemComparer`; for me I just left that off and made sure my 'item' class implemented `IComparable`

Answer (score 13):

Define a comparer implemeting [`IComparer<T>` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx):

```
public class PersonComparer : IComparer<Person>
{
    public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
    {
        return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
    }
}
```

And use [`SortedSet<T>` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) then:

```
        SortedSet<Person> list = new SortedSet<Person>(new PersonComparer());
        list.Add(new Person { Name = "aby", Age = "1" });
        list.Add(new Person { Name = "aab", Age = "2" });
        foreach (Person p in list)
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
```

---

If you are limited to usinf .NetFramework3.5, you could use [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) then:

```
SortedList<string, Person> list = 
          new SortedList<string, Person> (StringComparer.CurrentCulture);
Person person = new Person { Name = "aby", Age = "1" };
list.Add(person.Name, person);
person = new Person { Name = "aab", Age = "2" };
list.Add(person.Name, person);

foreach (Person p in list.Values)
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
```

Espesially read the *Remarks* section in the MSDN artcile, comparing this class and [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

If you're absolutely looking to use a list, try this:

```
int loc;
for(loc = 0; loc < people.Count && people[loc].Name.CompareTo(personToInsert.Name) < 0; loc++);
people.Insert(loc, personToInsert);
```

You can replace `people[loc].Name.CompareTo(personToInsert.Name) < 0` with whatever condition you're testing for - and you can change the sign to make it descending instead of ascending. Like `people[loc].Age < personToInsert.Age` for example would sort by age.

Comment: While this is not the most efficient sorted insertion for most lists, for very small ones (eg : less than 10 elements), this is probably faster than performing a binary search. Personally, I would have use a `while` instead of a `for` (but that does not matter).

Comment: This worked fine for me thanks. I just needed an easy lightweight way to insert a new item into the correct position in a drop down list bound to an observable collection.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) class. Simply use it instead of `List<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

`SortedList` is what you need.Create a StringComparer object and pass it to the constructor of the sortedlist.The elements are automatically sorted as new items are inserted.

```
StringComparer stringComp = StringComparer.CurrentCulture;
SortedList sl = new SortedList(stringComp);
sl.Add("B", "SECOND");
sl.Add("A", "FIRST");
sl.Add("C", "THIRD");
```