# How to make an ArrayList in C#

Tags: arraylist

I'm a beginner in C# and I just have to have some tasks for my teacher to continue moving on.

I kindly ask someone for assistance:

I have to write words in the console until the word 'end' is entered, and that's ok, but, I'm kinda lost when the program has to enlist words that are beginning with letter A, then in the next line words that initialize with letter B and finally with the C. After that it has to writeLine The Other Words.

Now, I have some pretty messy beginner code, and I don't think it would be much of a help, but I would appreciate if somebody even gives me a hint or an idea in what direction to think.

Answer (score 0):

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170896/insert-into-a-list-alphabetically-c-sharp) may help. It is not an ArrayList but because an ArrayList is a type of list, the pattern should hold true.