# Sort the file content based on the content

Tags: c#, linq

I have a file with some characteristics in particular, but, in this file, in column 30, I have a number, not sequential, 5 digit, and I would like to arrange the lines of this file, based on this numeroação, in ascending order.

For example:

```
sample sample sample1        00094
sample sample sample2        00001
sample sample sample3        00032
sample sample sample4        00491
sample sample sample5        00002
sample sample sample6        00010
sample sample sample7        00007
```

The sequential number is the 00094, 00001...

And the output is:

```
sample sample sample2        00001
sample sample sample5        00002
sample sample sample7        00007
sample sample sample6        00010
sample sample sample3        00032
sample sample sample1        00094
sample sample sample4        00491
```

I developed a sitema extremely pig, where I play everything in a list, and make a bubble sort, then, I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing this, perhaps using Linq, or even a different way.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `in column 30` how these columns are separated? By tab? By space?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188141/c-sharp-list-orderby-alphabetical-order

Comment: that is just in the column 30, I can have a name in the first 30 columns, can be use all the first 30 columns...

Comment: What's the separator between columns? How do you get 30th column?

Comment: characters... number, letters, spaces... anything, the numbers will be in the column 30 to 35

Comment: I think it's a fixed length text file that's how he got 30th column.

Comment: Updated my answer. I assume your indexing of columns starts with 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\yourFile.txt");

var sotedLines = lines.Skip(1)
                      .Take(lines.Length - 2)
                      .OrderBy(getKeyFromLine)
                      .ToArray();

sortedLines.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Now if your columns are separated by space, use next `getKeyFromLine` implementation:

```
Func<string, int> getKeyFromLine = line => int.Parse(line.Split(' ')[30]);
```

If it's simply the `30 - 35` one-based indexing digits in a line, then use

```
Func<string, int> getKeyFromLine = line => int.Parse(line.Substring(29, 5));
```

Comment: it's possible to make to not process the first and the last line of the file ?

Comment: If this were a big file and you didn't want to read it into memory, you could try something like `File.ReadLines(@"C:\temp\yourFile.txt")  .Skip(1).Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse().OrderBy(getKeyFromLine)` to keep the contents in an enumerable.

Comment: Evaluation of Reverse is deferred until you actually try to pull the data. In combination with File, though, you might be right. Most testing is needed.

Comment: It's deferred, but not streaming. When you read the first item - you will read all of them and `File.ReadLines` helps a little in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"text.txt");
var result = lines.AsParallel()
    .OrderBy(s => s.Split(' ').Last())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It's not space, that separates columns. By `column` OP means character position in a line. He needs 30-35 characters. It took some time to figure it out for me (see comments)

Comment: But the digits are still the last non-space chars on each line?

Comment: I don't know. It could be the case, that they aren't in the end of the line. Moreover, you need to order then alphanumerically, but not aplhabetically, so you probably also need to use `int.Parse`