# C# - is it possible to arrange ComboBox Items from a to z?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, combobox

I have a very messy long items full of strings in a combobox, and it would be lovely to just sort it from a to z to make it easier to track. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you using an object (like an array or `List<T>`) as a `.DataSource` for the combobox, or are you populating the `.Items` by yourself manually?

Comment: check this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188141/c-sharp-list-orderby-alphabetical-order

Comment: yes the source of the ComboBox itself is an array of strings

Comment: Depends on what UI technology you're working with. WinForms ComboBoxes have a [`Sorted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted.aspx) property. But you haven't told us what you're building. WinForms? WPF? HTML?

Comment: Have you tried: ComponentModel:SortDescription? Its in the WindowBase.dll

Comment: if you are sorting in code-behind, you can use linq before databinding: myList.OrderBy(x=>x.MyKey);

Comment: my bad, I'm building Windows 8 Store apps with C# and XAML

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are two possible ways that I could think of:

#### A) Use the WinForms Combobox `Sorted` Property

If you're using WinForms, you can use [`ComboBox.Sorted = true;`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted)

[image: ComboBox.Sorted]

#### B) Manually Sort your List with `OrderBy`

If the data in your combo box comes from in a form of a list, use [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) to the `List` of data you are going to put in the `ComboBox` *before* setting it.

Here's an example:

```cs
var myList = new List<string>() {"q","w","e","r","t","y"};
var sorted = a.OrderBy(c => c).ToArray()
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(sorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

turns out I can answer my own question, in Windows 8 C# app, ComboBox has Sort() properties that would simply arrange every items from a to z. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first I did not populate my dropdown combobox directly like this

```
AppCombBox1.Items.Add(comboboxvalue);
```

but instead i populated a list with same data (done in loop in code, which is searching through ini file for values):

```
List<string> TempList = new List<string>();
TempList.Add(comboboxvalue);
```

after list is populated, I sort it and after that I fill dropdown combobox with sorted values.

```
    TempList.Sort();
    foreach (string ListValue in TempList)
    {
        AppCombBox1.Items.Add(ListValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `Sorted Property to True`. It will sort the elements. I am fetching values from database and it works fine.

[image]