# How to order the list of model by string length property

Tags: c#, string, list, lambda

I have a class Users:

```
class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a list of users like `List<User> users`.
And I meet with the problem which sounds "How to order list by Name length string property?

I've tried something like this:

```
users.OrderBy(user=>user.Name.Length);
```

and unfortunately it didn't work.

Thanks for the reply and best regards.

Comment: It should have worked. What is you result ?

Comment: Daft question perhaps, but have you tried assigning the result back to the collection?

users = users.OrderBy(user=>user.Name.Length);

Comment: Probably a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188141/list-orderby-alphabetical-order?rq=1

Comment: @LDJ is right, but also convert result to List. `users = users.OrderBy(user=>user.Name.Length).ToList();`

Comment: I think you would have to do it this way: users = users.toList().OrderBy(user=>user.Name.Length);

Comment: @LDJ I'm kinda nocfuesd, it's obvious answer. I missed that. But about what Dmitry Bychenko has written what is better practise? Use Sort or OrderBy method? For me the OrderBy constrution with lambda it's more clear and readble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing that the list *doesn't have* `null` users as well as `null` names:

```
users.Sort((Comparison<User>) ((left, right) => 
  return left.Name.Length - right.Name.Length;
));
```

Note, that the code sorts an *existing* list `users`, while `OrderBy` creates a *new collection*:

```
users = users
  .OrderBy(user => user.Name.Length)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder what is better practise? Use Sort or OrderBy method? For me the OrderBy constrution with lambda it's more clear and readble

Comment: @vindemi: `Sort()` is a better solution here, since `OrderBy` *creates a new collection* which means additional resouces (time and memory) using.